# Tomcat Servlet IOErrors

Tags: flash, tomcat, servlets, ioerror

I have a servlet running in tomcat which I am connecting to directly via port 8080 from a Flash application.  The servlet provides data to the Flash app for processing.

Currently I'm getting around half a million requests per day and for the most part they are ok, but I'm getting IOError's every now and again (about 200 per day).

When I get an error, I'm logging the error to another servlet on a different server (via apache), so I can see when the first servlet is down, or responding with an issue.

The error I get is :

```
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]
```

I know that this is a general IOError (missing files ect) - but every request uses the same files, the same servlet, so I'm wondering why most would be ok - but occasionly I get the error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

The error is being reported from FLASH, so it's most likely related to an issue in Flash.  A quick search in Google shows that it usually means the URL can't be found??

Comment: Maybe its due to latency. The url is temporarily not found because the server is too busy to respond at that time.

Comment: @developerwjk - That was my first thought as well - but I've run robots against the server running 1000 calls per second without encountering this issue.  I'll investigate this further though - it's possibly still the issue...